# How to dynamically update child component properties

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use a video player (that could show any number of different videos) in this lightbox that accepts components as well as images:

[lightbox-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightbox-react)

Their docs give a simple example (pasted in below) that overlooks an important detail: a component in the lightbox may need to have parts of its content changed when displayed. So I need understand how to pass properties to the component that's being used for the `mainSrc` property of the lightbox.

I'm new to React, so I want to learn the right way to manage this. The only syntax I can find that will work for me is, in the parent:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    myVidPlayer: '',
  }
}
...
handleLightboxOpen() {
  this.setState({
    // re-create new video player every time:
    myVidPlayer: React.createElement(VidPlayer, { vidSrc: **real video source here** }),
  });
}
```

And in the render of the lightbox for the parent, I simply have `<Lightbox mainSrc={this.state.myVidPlayer}...>` which does work as needed, but I'm recreating the child component every time the lightbox pops up, which seems wrong.

I tried to do this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    myVidSrc: '',
  }
  this.vidPlayer = React.createElement(VidPlayer, { vidSrc: this.state.myVidSrc });
}
...
handleLightboxOpen() {
  this.setState({
    // does not work, child does not get updated:
    myVidSrc: '**real video source here**',
  });
}
```

And in the render of the lightbox for the parent, `<Lightbox mainSrc={this.vidPlayer}...>` but the child component "vidSrc" prop never gets updated when the parent state variable is changed. I had been under the impression that this should bubble down, but in this case, the prop seems to remain at its initial value.

Their example code is as follows (I'm replacing "VideoIframe" with my own "vidPlayer" per above):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Lightbox from 'lightbox-react';
import VideoIframe from 'components/cat-video';

const images = [
    VideoIframe,
    '//placekitten.com/1500/500',
    '//placekitten.com/4000/3000',
    '//placekitten.com/800/1200',
    '//placekitten.com/1500/1500'
];

export default class LightboxExample extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            photoIndex: 0,
            isOpen: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        const {
            photoIndex,
            isOpen,
        } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: true })}
                >
                    Open Lightbox
                </button>

                {isOpen &&
                    <Lightbox
                        mainSrc={images[photoIndex]}
                        nextSrc={images[(photoIndex + 1) % images.length]}
                        prevSrc={images[(photoIndex + images.length - 1) % images.length]}

                        onCloseRequest={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}
                        onMovePrevRequest={() => this.setState({
                            photoIndex: (photoIndex + images.length - 1) % images.length,
                        })}
                        onMoveNextRequest={() => this.setState({
                            photoIndex: (photoIndex + 1) % images.length,
                        })}
                    />
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't change a component's state from anywhere other than inside that component.  Trying to do so is a major anti-pattern.

Comment: @gravityplanx ok, I understand, but please view the gist of the question, how to change the video source in that component. So maybe the words I should have used were "change attributes/properties"?

Comment: You need to make a different component which has that as an option.  The `VideoIFrame` is just a hardcoded example of a video, it's not meant to be used for actual purposes.  You can see the inside of that component here though; https://github.com/treyhuffine/lightbox-react/blob/master/src/examples/cats/components/video.js

Comment: @gravityplanx I understand the example is simplified, and that is my question: how to manage properties of a real world version of such a component in this context? I need to pass it a dynamic property. How else do I ask the question more clearly? (you have to pretend that I have a similar component where the src is not a fixed string)

Comment: @gravityplanx might you be able to spot why the child isn't getting property updates when the parent state changes?

Comment: @gravityplanx I rewrote the question to reflect my working code, but I don't think it's efficient and I expect there's a better way to do it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing that update.

Passing props from a parent to a child component is a fundamental aspect of react and is very important to understand.  A simple example of this might look like such;

```
Child = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.someProp}</div>;
    }
});

Parent = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <Child someProp={"an example value"}/>;
    }
});
```

Mounting the `Parent` will now result in `<div>an example value</div>` being rendered to the display.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate the answer. However, I've seen this elsewhere and simply cannot reconcile it with the syntax of the lightbox-react widget and its example code contained in the question (can't see how to add props in the example code). Surely I'm missing the obvious. (also please note that the prop has to be able to change more than just at first render - lightbox could be called more than once for different video sources - I *think* if I can pass the prop as a parent state var it would work automatically?)

Comment: The way you wrote it in your example is totally fine! It's worth noting that `React.createElement(VidPlayer, { vidSrc: this.state.myVidSrc })` is exactly the same thing as writing `<VidPlayer vidSrc={this.state.myVidSrc}/>`, the only difference being whether you use traditional JS syntax or the newer JSX syntax. Otherwise it looks like a totally normal piece of react code. Also, don't worry too much initially about costly renders.  React is built to cache and re-use components in very efficient ways behind the scenes. Until you actually experience a problem, just trust react to do it's thing!